# how to deploy c++ application and create setup file for my music player

Tags: c++, deployment, installation, installshield

I have developed one music player in C++. Now I want to create setup.exe for that application so that i can put that application for downloading for other users. When we download some software from website we get setup for installing that application. I want to know how can i create that setup file for me cpp application. Please help as soon as possible

Comment: Inno setup? http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

For Windows platform
There are loads of solutions some free some not

personnaly I'd recommend wix (it's free, it uses windows installer technology) but for some it's overkill
checkout
http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/
for a great example/cook book

Others include

1. install shield http://www.installshield.com/ (used to have a cool debugger, but not free)
2. inno Setup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)
3. Wise Installer (OK looks like it's dead!)
4. Do it by hand using ORCA (an MSI editor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx)
5. WIX 3.X (http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/115492)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the [free edition of Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html). Here is 5 minutes tutorial showing how to do it: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html

To create projects of type "**Simple**" you don't need a license and you can deploy the package for commercial purposes too.